# Windows 7 network connections

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

I am having an *extreme* problem with my network adapter. I recently discovered that my onboard ethernet adapter was *somehow* incompatible with Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Yesterday, I got a brand new *wired* network card. After installing it in the PCI-E 1x slot I started my computer up.

I checked my network, and as I was expecting to see a "Connected to Network" message. I got a message in my connections that I *was* connected, *but* it was to "Unidentified Network" with "No Internet Access." I rebooted, just to get a "No connections Available" message in my connections box.

In the Network and Sharing Center I had a message saying to plug in an ethernet cable. Obviously, I had already done this. I tried with another cable, even directly connecting it to the cable modem itself (I originally had it connected to port 1 on a Cisco Valet.)

I even tried resetting the "TCP/IP" stack, also to no avail. After letting the computer down for a while, I booted back into Windows 7, and what do you know, "Unidentified Network, No Internet Access." After tinkering around some more, like setting the IP up, it went back to "Network cable unplugged."

I am now not knowing what to do. I also tried other things like:

- Restarting
- Switching Cables
- Disabling and Re-Enabling
- Updating Drivers (all were up to date!)

All to no avail.
Thank you for all of your answers, and I would be glad to provide more information,
Scott

P.S. I am only 12, so please do not get mad if there is an obvious answer!

UPDATE:

I've removed all image links, but here's the Cmd for netstat -rn on the Laptop which works:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\NCS Customer>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 43...3e 4b d6 f8 3f 9e ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 42...1c 4b d6 0f 92 d7 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #10
 40...70 71 bc 4f 95 ca ......Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller #
9
 11...1c 4b d6 f8 3f 9e ......Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
 44...7a 79 05 f1 49 1e ......Hamachi Network Interface
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 49...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 48...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 50...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 51...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 61...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          5.0.0.1      5.241.73.30   9256
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.136     25
          5.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
      5.241.73.30  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
    5.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.136  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          5.0.0.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 14     58 2001::/32                On-link
 14    306 2001:0:4137:9e76:14d7:3516:3f57:fe77/128
                                    On-link
 44    276 2620:9b::/96             On-link
 44    276 2620:9b::5f1:491e/128    On-link
 44    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    306 fe80::14d7:3516:3f57:fe77/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 fe80::4cf9:7e9b:e70d:857f/128
                                    On-link
 44    276 fe80::504a:2f89:a560:9715/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 44    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  0 4294967295 2620:9b::/96             On-link
===========================================================================

C:\Users\NCS Customer>
```

This is the arp -a command on the laptop:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\NCS Customer>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 43...3e 4b d6 f8 3f 9e ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 42...1c 4b d6 0f 92 d7 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #10
 40...70 71 bc 4f 95 ca ......Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller #
9
 11...1c 4b d6 f8 3f 9e ......Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
 44...7a 79 05 f1 49 1e ......Hamachi Network Interface
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 49...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 48...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 50...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 51...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 61...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          5.0.0.1      5.241.73.30   9256
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.136     25
          5.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
      5.241.73.30  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
    5.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.136  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       5.241.73.30   9256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.136    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          5.0.0.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 14     58 2001::/32                On-link
 14    306 2001:0:4137:9e76:14d7:3516:3f57:fe77/128
                                    On-link
 44    276 2620:9b::/96             On-link
 44    276 2620:9b::5f1:491e/128    On-link
 44    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    306 fe80::14d7:3516:3f57:fe77/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 fe80::4cf9:7e9b:e70d:857f/128
                                    On-link
 44    276 fe80::504a:2f89:a560:9715/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 44    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  0 4294967295 2620:9b::/96             On-link
===========================================================================

C:\Users\NCS Customer>
```

This is the non working desktop for natstat -rn:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...00 a1 b0 00 02 14 ......VIA Velocity-Family Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Now here is the desktop with the arp -a command:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...00 a1 b0 00 02 14 ......VIA Velocity-Family Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Windows\system32>
```

And for arp -a it comes back with an err saying no ARP entries found.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Did you install the driver for the new card?

Comment: Yes. I also tried that. All drivers are up to date.

Comment: You seem to have access to the network on some other computer, you should compare that computers settings (specifically IP, netmask and gateway (dns)) and post them here. Can you ping your router? cmd.exe -> `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` xx.. being your routers IP. Do not reuse the same IP on different network-devices, but use the same subnet (like 192.168.0.x) and subnetmask like (255.255.255.0).

Comment: I edited your question to make it a bit more readable, feel free to revert the changes or edit it again. Welcome to Superuser btw ;)

Comment: Thank you! Also, I don't have enough rep. I can't post images, but I could post them on a site like Imgur and link to them!

Comment: No, don't need images.  
Open a Cmd window and type `netstat -rn`. Cut and paste the output into your question (your mouse may not work here use the right-click menu and `ctl-c`) surrounded by <pre></pre> tag pair. Do the same for `arp -a`

Comment: In your network connection propertied tab turn of IPv6. Reset your router anytime you change cables or reset windows.
In Device Explorer does you network device show up and is it working? In your network connection propertied tab turn of IPv6.

Comment: For your first comment, I am on that now. For your second comment : The first thing: HOW?!?! After trying to  do that, I couldn't click uninstall. The second: I always do that. And third: Yes. It shows the network adapter working properly.

Comment: @ScottLarimer -- Do you have a Dial-Up Connection? Because this thing `Unidentified Network` is very obvious for me, and others with Dial-Up connection.

Comment: @Asif No. It is Comcast/Xfinity Cable Broadband internet.

Comment: This is above my head than sorry..may [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Set-up-a-broadband-DSL-or-cable-connection) helps you.

Comment: @Asif Sorry, I have tried this to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, your provider (or modem) have settings that allow internet access only from allowed network cards. As usually, provider limits the access by MAC address of network card. If so, you must edit modem setting and add new card MAC address to allowing list or provide you new MAC address to internet provider.

[About MAC](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocolsip/g/bldef_mac.htm)

[Mac Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering)

Comment: ummmmmm..... What?

Comment: @ScottLarimer Check links.

Comment: I have a Cisco M10 Router. MAC address filtering is disabled.